# DataFormatString formats percentage wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this field from the database which is:

DataType: Numeric (7, 3)

So will allow max number

9999.99

Into the database.

I put the number

10.000

Into the database, and now I'm retrieving out of the database using:

```
<asp:GridView>
```

I specify:

```
<asp:BoundField DataFormatString="{0:p}" />
```

And it outputs

1,000.00%

Which is suppose to be

10.00%

Why isn't it?

I also can't put <% %> server runtime tags into a:

```
<asp:TemplateField />
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Percentages are stored as decimals where 0 = 0% and 1 = 100%.  You should store your value as 0.1, not 10.

The line `<asp:BoundField DataFormatString="{0:p}" />` will format your value of 10.000 to 1,000.00%.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)

Comment: I will get on it right away! a change or numeric(5,3) as 9.9999

Answer (score 8):

It's behaving exactly as described in the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k) page on MSDN:

> Result: Number multiplied by 100 and displayed with a percent symbol.

So *either* you shouldn't use that format string, *or* you should keep your value as a proportion of 1, rather than as a percentage.